# Windows 7 systeminfo reporting incorrect System Boot Time?

Tags: windows-7, boot, troubleshooting, time

I work 9-5 and switch my PC off when I leave the office each day. When doing timesheets I need to know what time I got to work, so I usually use cmd > systeminfo for finding the System Boot Time.

Since upgrading to Windows 7 however, it's started reporting bizarre numbers between 11pm-2am instead of 8-9am. Today it says it booted at 11:34pm last night!

I checked the event log and there is no entries between when I shutdown at 5:30pm yesterday and booted around 8am this morning.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: where are you (what timezone)? sounds as if it's a broken timezone thing -- if it thinks your current hw clock is set to GMT and subtracts to get PST, but your hw clock is actually set to PST, the result will be pretty far off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find out when Windows was last restarted?](http://superuser.com/questions/523726/how-can-i-find-out-when-windows-was-last-restarted)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same - Windows 7 x64, since few days after enabling hibernation, after boot the system timer sometimes shows different time.

There's a great writeup here by Joey about what could be the case: [Windows XP clock set incorrectly after resume from sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/57005/windows-xp-clock-set-incorrectly-after-resume-from-sleep)

I tried setting Windows to auto-sync time, and it seems to have helped... but too little time yet to draw conclusions (I think once it didn't work).

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same issue and found this [How can I find out when Windows was last restarted?](https://superuser.com/questions/523726/how-can-i-find-out-when-windows-was-last-restarted)

It's correct. Command "net statistics workstation" reveals the actual boot time (or near enough to answer the original question).

Comment: How about quoting, what you feel, is the relevant information from that answer or flagging this question as a duplicate of that existing question?